# Camera and screen sync

Tags: algorithm, camera, screen, frame-rate

Problem Description:

[image]

we have a camera that is sending video of a live sports game in 30 frames per second.
on the other side we have a screen that is representing immediately every fram that is coming.

Assumptions
*frames will arrive in order

1.what will be the experience for a person that is wathcing the screen?

2.what can we do in order to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your playback will have very variable framerate which would cause visible artifacts during any smooth movement ...

To remedy this You need to implement image FIFO that will cover bigger time that is your worst delay difference (Idealy at least 2x times more). So if you got 300ms-100ms delay difference and 30 fps then minimal FIFO size is:

```
n = 2 * (300-100) * 0.001 * 30 = 12 images
```

Now the reproduction should be like this:

1. **init playback**

   simply start obtaining images into FIFO until the FIFO is half FULL (contains images for biggest delay difference)
2. **playback**

   so any incoming image is inserted into FIFO at time of receival (unless FIFO is full in which case you wait until you have room to place new image or skip frame). Meanwhile in some thread or timer (that runs in parallel) you fetch image from FIFO every 1/30 seconds and render it (if the FIFO is empty you use last image and you can even go to bullet #1 again).
3. **playback stop**

   once FIFO is empty for longer duration then some threshold (no new frames are incoming) you stop the playback.

The FIFO size reserve and point when to start playback depends on the image source timing properties (so it does not overrun nor underrun the FIFO)...

In case you need to implement your own FIFO class then cyclic buffer of constant size is your friend (so you do not need to copy all the stored images on FIFO in/out operations).